# Apache Fix Leverage Browser Cache

Tags: apache, browser-cache

I have this code to fix leverage brower cache in my websites for apache, but I think mod_expires is not enabled

```
# Leverage Browser Caching
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
  ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Make a php file which contains `<?php print_r(apache_get_modules()); ?>`, run it and then look if `mod_expires` is in the list. If so, the module is enabled.

Comment: After using your code, my site will print this message The (site name) page isn’t working, (site name) is currently unable to handle this request.
500

Comment: Edit your question! And if you get a HTTP 500, check webserver logfiles.

Comment: my server giving error in error log_file---PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function apache_get_modules()

Comment: Your code is work on wampserer it shows all modules, but how can i enable leaverage browser cache module in web server